# css styles aren't applied on classes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a social card (similar to Facebook). I don't know why I can't modify my classes inside CSS, but when I style them directly they work.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 145px;
}

.image-section {
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 90px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class=”card”>
  <div class=”image-section”>
    <img class=”image” src="images/photo.png">
  </div>
  <div class=”info-section”>
    <p class=”name”>Roland</p>
    <p class=”tag”>@roland00</p>
    <p class=”gender”>Male</p>
  </div>
  <div class=”button-section”>
    <button class=”btn” type=”button”>Follow</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then they probably get overridden by some other styles, check the styles applied in dev tools!

Comment: The problem is because of the invalid double quote characters you're using. You're using `”` and `”`, not `"`. Fix that and your code works - https://jsfiddle.net/u6ed5scg/. I'd also suggest using a better HTML IDE than whatever you currently do, as this error should be highlighted by any good syntax linter. I'm voting to close as a typographical issyue.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan
I typed the code in Word, to practice myself, and I didn't realize they came out like that.
Fixed!

Comment: Glad to help. Word is a dreadful HTML editor I'm afraid. I'd suggest something like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) - it's free )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its applying you have mistake in your double inverted comma.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 145px;
}

.image-section {
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 90px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image-section">
    <img class="image" src="images/photo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="info-section">
    <p class="name">Roland</p>
    <p class="tag">@roland00</p>
    <p class="gender">Male</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button-section">
    <button class="btn" type="button">Follow</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when naming the classes in html use this `class="name"` instead of `class=”card”`

Answer (score -2):

I can see only one reasons:
You put css styling tag after the html code.

Comment: Location of CSS rules has absolutely no bearing whatsoever.